# What property of ranked poset ensures that it is determined by its vertex-facet incidences?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, posets

For a convex polytope, its face poset is combinatorially determined by vertex-facet incidences. Now suppose we have an arbitrary finite poset that is *ranked*, so I can still speak of vertices and facets. What property should be satisfied for vertex-facet incidences to still store all the information? Is it the property of being an abstract polytope, or will something weaker be enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $L$ is a finite lattice, then $L$ is determined by its subposet of elements that are join-irreducible or meet-irreducible (or both). In particular, if the  only join-irreducibles are atoms (vertices) and only meet-irreducibles are coatoms (facets), then $L$ is determined by the incidences between its vertices and facets. See for instance Exercise 3.27 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second edition.

Comment: Oh thank you very much! This makes a certain proof a lot simpler than I though.